# How to make a 'unconfigured' and 'ready' RAID drive 'online'?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, megacli

I have 2 drives in RAID 1 configuration, as Ubuntu 16 boot drives. One of the drives failed and recovered by itself and I now have the following output:

```
root@server:/home/admin/megacli/Linux# megasasctl
a0       PERC H310 Adapter        encl:1 ldrv:1  batt:FAULT, module missing, pack missing, charge failed
a0d0       931GiB RAID 1   1x2  DEGRADED
unconfigured:  a0e*s0  
a0e*s0      931GiB        ready   
a0e*s1      931GiB  a0d0  online  

root@server:/home/admin/megacli/Linux# megacli -pdgetmissing -aALL

    Adapter 0 - Missing Physical drives

    No.   Array   Row   Size Expected
    0     0       0     953344 MB

Exit Code: 0x00
```

What megacli commands do I need to enter to get the a0e*s0 back online like the other drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the device "online" with

```
MegaCli –PDOnline -PhysDrv[XXX:XXX] -aN
```

Or maybe if needed set it as "unconfigured good" with

```
megacli -PDMakeGood -PhysDrv[XXX:XXX] -Force -aN
```